# Disable service worker in development mode

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

During development, my web app project serves files on a development server at `https://localhost`. However, Chrome blocks its service worker from accessing the server (because it does not trust the self-signed https certificate). Is there a way to disable/unregister service workers in Chrome when in development mode?

Answer (score 45):

You can use the chrome devtools, and under *Application>Service Workers* path select the *Update on refresh* checkbox

[image]

You can also use the *Bypass for network* checkbox to avoid Service worker's register event form firing.

Comment: Yes, but every time I refresh page the Service worker gets registered. I dont want that to happen. thx

Comment: Then select the `Bypass for network` option shown in above image to avoid the registration

Comment: for me a combination of `Bypass for network` with clicking `stop` did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

1. Navigate: `Dev Tools > Application > Service Workers`
2. Enable: `Bypass for network`

This will prevent the browser from referencing the service worker for content. Very useful for development when you do not want to do cache busting on every save.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a brute-force approach:

```
const fn = () => {};

navigator.serviceWorker.register = () => new Promise(fn, fn);
```

(tested in Chrome Canary and Firefox Developer Edition)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is specific to a NextJS project using [Next-PWA](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa) library to implement PWA, but it uses Google's Workbox under the hood to run service-workers, so it might help someone dig deeper.

```
// next.config.js

const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
 
module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    // ...
  }
})
```

References:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790#issuecomment-729698643
https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pwa?activeTab=readme#configuration